# Apache: Copy all mp3 files from subfolders into another folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, copy

I have a files folder with many subfolders (MediaWiki). Some of these contain mp3 files. I want them all copied into another folder (without subfolders).

How could I do that?

Apache 2, Ubuntu 12

Comment: Why would you want to copy them without subfolders? What if you have duplicate file names? Also, this is more appropriate for SuperUser, so I've flagged it to move.

Comment: Never mind, I grab them via URL export.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it demonstrates no effort or understanding on the asker's part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you get yourself familiar with `man 1 find`:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.mp3' -exec mv -t DESTDIR {} \;
$
```